# Simple php regex question

Tags: php, regex, string, uri

I have a string:

```
$uri = "start/test/go/";
```

Basically I need to know which regular expression and PHP function I can use to match the first item with a forward slash ("/") and remove it from the string. It should also work if the first item is not start and is anything else which might also have a space in it.
So all these combination should work:

```
$uri = "start_my_test/test/go/";
$uri2 = "start my test/test/go/";
```

Then after the RegEx it should always return:

```
$newUri = "test/go/";
```

Oh and the other side of the string could be anything as well, So basically I want it to delete anything before the first occurrence of a forward slash.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/^[^\/]*\//' , '', $subject);
```

This says "start at the beginning of the string" `^`, "match any number of characters that are not a forward slash" `[^\/]*`, then match a single forward slash `\/` -- and "replace the whole matched thing with nothing" `''`.

Comment: Since this was a regex question, your answer is correct and works. But performance wise the non regex answers are more feasible.

Comment: Well, the performance differences are really minuscule -- we're talking a few processing cycles that nobody will notice unless you are running the thing hundreds of thousands of times in a row. So it comes down to code clarity, maintainability, and stylistic choices. In terms of code clarity, `strstr` might be a better solution for this problem, but stylistically I tend to prefer regex anyway, because I personally find them familiar and easy to read.

Answer (score 4):

Use `strstr` to find the first occurrence of a string in php.

That in itself should return the remainder of the string.

[see here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: To fully remove the string like I wanted I had to add a substr around the strstr to remove the left over forward slash at the beginning. e.g. substr(strstr($uri, "/"), 1);

Answer (score 0):

regex is too expensive an operation for what you need. use `strpos` and `substr` instead

```
$position = strpos($needle, $haystack);
if ( $position !== false ) {
  $result = substr($needle, $position + 1);
}
```