# Using PHP how do I test a string for a pattern then alter it?

Tags: php, regex

In PHP given this string:

```
$string = '/sometext?123#abc/moretext';
```

How can I test for the existence of the pattern "?123#abc/" which will always be enclosed by "?" and "/" but have varying inner-text that may include any text and symbols?  The text outside of the pattern will also be different.  I need to do this:

```
if ($string includes pattern ?*/) {
  //load the inner value into a variable

  //then remove the entire patern including the leading "?" and trailing "/" and replace with a single "/"

}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: you've answered your own question: use a regex.

Comment: strpos can give you first occurrence of the substring if you dont wanna go regex route.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Use [`preg_replace`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: For alter use javascript: `<?PHP echo '<script>alert("Message");</script>'; ?>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$s = '/sometext?123#abc/moretext';
$matches = array();
$t = preg_match('#\?(.*?)\/#s', $s, $matches);
if($matches[1])
   echo "match";
else
   echo "not";
```

## Output

```
match
```

## Codepad

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  I'm curious... is the $matches = array(); part required?  Also, I can just test for $t, correct?

Comment: @Inator Yes `$matches = array();` is required.  :)

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, why are you using `$` as the regex delimiter?  That seems like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks for pointing out. Actually I was just testing with that. If you think its bad idea than I will change it to `?`. And I have seen so many answers with `$` as delimiter, so I also used it.

Comment: Can you point out some of those answers?  Both `$` and `?` are regex metacharacters; if you use them as delimiters, you can't use them as metacharacters.

Comment: @AlanMoore I don't have there links but i can only remember that I have seen answers with `$` as delimiter. Can you tell me what character should be used as delimiter in regex?

Comment: Here you go: [Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar - Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493606/how-do-i-fix-a-malformed-url-in-php/16498635#16498635.  I credited you for the answer.  Feel free to improve it if you see fit.

Comment: @Inator, The answer you chose does not answer the whole question.  2) To do everything you want, the answer you chose would require performing another regex match, which is inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = '/sometext?123#abc/moretext';
$pattern = '/\\?(.*?)\\//';

if( $pieces = preg_split($pattern, $string, Null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)) {
    echo($pieces[1] . "\n");
    unset($pieces[1]);
    echo(implode("/", $pieces) . "\n");
}

?>

--output:--

~/php_programs$ php 1.php 
123#abc
/sometext/moretext
```